# Part of the robot (UR5 with robotiq gripper) not showing up in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, gripper, universal-robot, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working on a simulation combining the UR5 arm and a robotiq 2-finger gripper together. The arm shows up completely in gazebo, but the base of the gripper does not show up despite added intertial parameters. But in Rviz it shows up just fine. So I guess gazebo doesn't like something about the robotiq xacro file, but I can't find out what. Hopefully someone can help me.
I'm using ROS Indigo and Gazebo 2.2.3.

Here you can see how it looks in rviz and gazebo: https://i.imgur.com/vHwSoId.png
Sometimes that triangle shows up, but not every time: https://i.imgur.com/VPYqIdS.png

This is the xacro file containing the description for the robotiq gripper: https://github.com/philwall3/robotiq/blob/patch-1/robotiq_2f_model/model/robotiq_2f_85.urdf.xacro

And this is the top level xacro that combines the arm and gripper and that I load in gazebo:

```
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro"
       name="ur5" >

    <!-- THE ROBOT -->
    <link name="world" />

    <!-- UR from ROS-i repos -->
    <xacro:include filename="$(find ur_description)/urdf/ur5.urdf.xacro" />
    <joint name="world_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="world" />
        <child link = "simple_arm_base_link" />
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
    </joint>
    <!--xacro:ur5_robot prefix="simple_arm_" joint_limited="false"/-->
    <xacro:ur5_robot prefix="simple_arm_" joint_limited="false"/>

    <!-- Robotiq from Beta Robots fork-->
    <xacro:include filename="$(find robotiq_2f_model)/model/robotiq_2f_85.urdf.xacro" />
    <xacro:robotiq_2f_85 name="simple_gripper" parent="simple_arm_tool0" precise_collision="false" adaptive_transmission="false" with_pads="true">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 1.5708" />
    </xacro:robotiq_2f_85>

    <gazebo>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">       
      </plugin>
    </gazebo> 
</robot>
```

And here is the launch file:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="headless" default="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>

  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find myrobot_gazebo)/worlds/myrobot.world"/>
    <!--arg name="paused" value="false"/-->    
    <!-- more default parameters can be changed here -->
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
<arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>

  </include>

  <!-- Convert an xacro and put on parameter server -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find myrobot_description)/urdf/join_macro.xacro" />

  <!-- Spawn a robot into Gazebo -->
  <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model myrobot -z 0.1" respawn="false" output="screen" />

  <include file="$(find myrobot_gazebo)/launch/controller_utils.launch"/>
  <rosparam file="$(find myrobot_gazebo)/config/gripper_controller_robotiq.yaml" command="load"/> 
  <node name="gripper_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="gripper --shutdown-timeout 0.5" />

  <!--include file="$(find ur_gazebo)/launch/controller_utils.launch"/-->
  <rosparam file="$(find ur_gazebo)/controller/arm_controller_ur5.yaml" command="load"/>
  <node name="arm_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" args="spawn arm_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>    

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276122/part-of-the-robot-(ur5-with-robotiq-gripper)-not-showing-up-in-gazebo/) by [philwall3](https://answers.ros.org/users/32152/philwall3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.ros.org/users/4654/chapulina/) on 2017-11-21**:
It looks like there could be something weird with the DAE file, have you tried opening it on another program such as Blender? It's worth it looking at the normal directions and maybe re-exporting the mesh.

**Comment by [philwall3](https://answers.ros.org/users/32152/philwall3/) on 2017-11-21**:
Thanks for the suggestion! It's opening fine in Blender. Also Rviz and the moveit assistant wizard both open and show the base just fine. So I'm confident the .dae file is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was not able to solve the problem with above package. But I found another package that works fine for me: https://github.com/StanleyInnovation/robotiq_85_gripper

---

Originally posted by [philwall3](https://answers.ros.org/users/32152/philwall3/) with karma: 16 on 2017-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0